# New Contact registration or Contact's own data change -- after approval only

Tags: registration

Is it possible to restrict the new contact registration and the modification the contact's own data so, that the contact can only lead the registration or the data modification, and a specific role has to approve?

I'd like to have a similar process as the Drupal user's registration process.

Now I'm using Drupal7 with CiviCRM 5.42.

Comment: The short answer is No. The longer answer may involve making the user submit eg a Webform and then having the Admin manually add the changes (we have one client who does this because the really need to avoid bad overwriting of data)